# Rename files during upload within Wordpress backend

Tags: wordpress, plugins, file-rename

is there a way to rename files during the upload progress within the `Wordpress 3.0` backend? I would like to have a consistent naming of files, especially for images.

I think an 12 (+-) digit hash value of the original filename or something similar would be awesome. Any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> But it would really be easier to do that before uploading files.

Not quite sure about that - this seems fairly easy;

```
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/3261107/247223
 */
function so_3261107_hash_filename( $filename ) {
    $info = pathinfo( $filename );
    $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename( $filename, $ext );

    return md5( $name ) . $ext;
}

add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'so_3261107_hash_filename', 10 );
```

This filter creates a 32 character hash of the original filename, preserving the file extension. You could chop it down a little using `substr()` if you wanted to.

This filter runs once the file has been uploaded to a temporary directory on your server, but before it is resized (if applicable) and saved to your uploads folder.

Note that there is no risk of file overwrite - in the event that a newly hashed file is the same as one that already exists, WordPress will try appending an incrementing digit to the filename until there is no longer a collision.

### WordPress Plugin

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Hash Upload Filename
 * Plugin URI:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259696
 * Description: Rename uploaded files as the hash of their original.
 * Version:     0.1
 */

/**
 * Filter {@see sanitize_file_name()} and return an MD5 hash.
 *
 * @param  string $filename
 * @return string
 */
function so_3261107_hash_filename( $filename ) {
    $info = pathinfo( $filename );
    $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename( $filename, $ext );

    return md5( $name ) . $ext;
}

add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'so_3261107_hash_filename', 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks TheDeadMusic, i thought about something similar. But hoped there is an ready to use plugin or something easy to customize, I'm not a specialist in writing wordpress plugins or hooks but i'll will try it. Thank you furthermore for your suggestions. Awesome guys at stackoverflow :)

Comment: I've made an update to my answer - save the code in a file as `hash-upload.php` and pop it in your plugins folder :)

Comment: How awesome is that! I'm really thrilled about that:) Currently i found a solution my own. I have costumized the upload+ plugin. Works also. But your solution is much much more elegant. Less overhead too. Thank you very much TheDeadMedic (notTheDeadMusic -sorry) Can't vote once again!

Comment: As i asked here-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265350/change-wordpress-gallery-shortcode-slug-to-filename. Why it does not change the post_name too? Same if i set the plugin priority to 1.

Answer (score 11):

http://wpapi.com/change-image-name-to-wordpress-post-slug-during-upload/

BTW:

Add filter to `sanitize_file_name` is totally wrong, as `sanitize_file_name()` function is a helper function to format string, it may be used elsewhere like plugins or themes.

```
function wp_modify_uploaded_file_names($file) {
    $info = pathinfo($file['name']);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename($file['name'], $ext);

    $file['name'] = uniqid() . $ext; // uniqid method
    // $file['name'] = md5($name) . $ext; // md5 method
    // $file['name'] = base64_encode($name) . $ext; // base64 method

    return $file;
}

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wp_modify_uploaded_file_names', 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

I've made a plugin for it. I did it because i was having too much trouble with my clients trying to upload images with special characters

http://wordpress.org/plugins/file-renaming-on-upload

Answer (score 3):

I implemented the same thing, I wanted a more random filename, than the original, as the site I am using this for is for pics only and all files are in one directory.

i did the following

```
return md5($ip . uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . $ext;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was really looking for a plugin that could do it properly, and finally I ended up making this one myself. It's available on my blog: http://www.meow.fr/media-file-renamer ! If you use it, please give me a feedback :) I sincerely hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't autorename file with the media library function. I would recommend to rename files before you upload them. Even after uploading a file you can't rename it throug WordPress but only through FTP.

The only way to do that would be a plugin that hooks itself into the media library upload process. But it would really be easier to do that before uploading files.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I know i can't rename it with the media library function. That is why i ask :)

For this Project it would be easier to do it within the upload progress. It's a usability feature for people who are not very familiar with batch renaming and ftp.