# Change wordpress gallery shortcode slug to filename

Tags: wordpress, url, gallery, slug, shortcode

Is it possible to change the attachment page slug to the referring filename? In short... i use the [Gallery Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) to build a simple page based gallery.

I change the orignal filename (like DSC1223.jpg) during the upload process (to 3b1871561aab.jpg) but it does not appery as slug within the url. It uses only DSC1223.

Is there anyway to change ist?

Regards, Steve

The best way would be to write something like this in my functions.php

```
function twentyten_filter_wp_handle_upload () {

    $upload =  wp_handle_upload();

}

add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', 'twentyten_filter_wp_handle_upload', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Do you need to automate this in some form? Or is it a one off? A quick solution is to edit the `post_name` field in the `wp_posts` database table - that's where you'll find `DSC1223` is kept and used.

Comment: Yes, i need to automate this. It it would be awesome during the upload progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the [hash upload filename plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259696/3261107#3261107) and you should be good to go;

```
/**
 * Filter new attachments and set the post_name the same as the hashed
 * filename.
 * 
 * @param int $post_ID
 */
function change_attachment_name_to_hash($post_ID)
{
    $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    $name = trim( substr($info['basename'], 0, -(1 + strlen($info['extension'])) ) );
    wp_update_post(array(
        'ID' => $post_ID,
        'post_name' => $name
    ));
}
add_action('add_attachment', 'change_attachment_name_to_hash');
```

Don't hesitate to ask if you're not sure what each line does!

UPDATE:

This function hooks onto the `add_attachment` event, just after a new attachment is saved to the database. This action is called from within `wp_insert_attachment()`.

We first grab the **filename** of the attachment (`get_attached_file()`). Then we use a native PHP function [**pathinfo()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the path components, and strip the directory path and file extension away.

Then we call `wp_update_post()`, updating the `post_name` of the attachment in the database.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could explain your code :) I've found the correct part of code in in the wp-admin/include/media.php around line 186. But i can't find a way to hook this function because i really don't know how to pass the data. Thanks again... Mr. TheDeadMedic! If i can help you somehow... My home is the Frontend:)

Comment: "I've found the correct part of code in in the wp-admin/include/media.php around line 186" - what do you mean by that? Just add ALL the code in THIS answer to the bottom of the plugin code from my OTHER answer, and you're good to go.

Comment: Sure. I have merged both pieces of your Code and it works perfectly! I meant that the `function media_handle_upload()` normally does the job. It is the relevant code for title and caption defaults and more. It will handle the file upload POST itself and creating the attachment post. Can't explain it better.

Comment: You're right - `media_handle_upload()` does the job, and still does - these functions just 'hook' onto actions that run during it's process, and slightly alter things to your requirements.

Comment: Ok TheDeadMedic, Thank you for your explanation. For an non programmer it is hard to understand what is going on. add_action(), add_filter, hook. But once you understand it, Wordpress becomes more flexible. Thanks again for your competent answer.