# Rename files during upload within Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, filenames, rename

I am trying to rename upload filenames match the Post Title.

This other thread shows how to rename to hash:
[Rename files during upload within Wordpress backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259696/rename-files-during-upload-within-wordpress-backend)

Using this code:

```
function make_filename_hash($filename) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename($filename, $ext);
    return md5($name) . $ext;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'make_filename_hash', 10);
```

Does anyone know the code to rename the file to match Post Title.extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

barakadam's answer is almost correct, just a little correction based on the comment I left below his answer.

```
function new_filename($filename, $filename_raw) {
    global $post;
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $new = $post->post_title . $ext;
    // the if is to make sure the script goes into an indefinate loop
    if( $new != $filename_raw ) {
        $new = sanitize_file_name( $new );
    }
    return $new;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'new_filename', 10, 2);
```

Explanation of code:

Lets assume you upload a file with the original filename called `picture one.jpg` to a post called "My Holiday in Paris/London".

When you upload a file, WordPress removes special characters from the original filename using the [`sanitize_file_name()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/formatting.php#L800) function.

Right at the bottom of the function is where the filter is.

```
// line 854 of wp-includes/formatting.php
return apply_filters('sanitize_file_name', $filename, $filename_raw);
```

At this point, $filename would be `picture-one.jpg`. Because we used `add_filter()`, our new_filename() function will be called with $filename as `picture-one.jpg` and $filename_raw as `picture one.jpg`.

Our new_filename() function then replaces the filename with the post title with the original extension appended. If we stop here, the new filename `$new` would end up being `My Holiday in Paris/London.jpg` which all of us know is an invalid filename.

Here is when we call the sanitize_file_name function again. Note the conditional statement there. Since `$new != $filename_raw` at this point, it tries to sanitize the filename again.

[`sanitize_file_name()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/formatting.php#L800) will be called and at the end of the function, `$filename` would be `My-Holiday-in-Paris-London.jpg` while `$filename_raw` would still be `My Holiday in Paris/London.jpg`. Because of the `apply_filters()`, our `new_filename()` function runs again. But this time, because `$new == $filename_raw`, thats where it ends.

And `My-Holiday-in-Paris-London.jpg` is finally returned.

Comment: +1 Nice write-up! What happens if the same file is uploaded twice?

Comment: @brasofilo can you take at look at this scenario?  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809555/rename-files-during-upload-within-wordpress-and-gravity-form)

Comment: `global $post;` returns `NULL`, any idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (considering `$post` is your post variable, make it global):

```
function new_filename($filename) {
    global $post;
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    return $post->post_title . $ext;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'new_filename', 10);
```

Did I understand you?

Comment: You want to do something to the post title as it might not be safe for naming a file. Post titles with slashes would certainly break the code. Yes, WordPress sanitizes filenames of uploaded files, but adding the filter overrides it and you need to call it again. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/formatting.php#L814