# Rename files during upload within Wordpress and Gravity Form

Tags: wordpress

Renaming the file is working as instructed here [Rename files during upload within Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751377/rename-files-during-upload-within-wordpress#comment18984378_13751828)

In my scenario all files will be uploaded via a gravity form on a page (`/upload`).

This method is naming every file `Upload.mp3` instead of `Post Name.mp3`.

> [image: custom field value]

> [image: permalink]

Can this method be modified to work in my scenario?

Comment: The function you are using is picking up "upload" as the post name for $post->post_title. That is the name of the post (actually, page) from which you are doing the upload. So you want to pick up the name of the destination post, I suppose. But you are giving us no hint on the relationship between your MP3 upload and the destination post or post title... How is your upload associated with a certain post? If you answer this clearly, the solution to your problem should be easy.

Comment: Please, post the actual code you are using. Each Question should be a fresh start, and even a comma can change **everything** ;)

Comment: Any user can initiate an upload via gravity form here http://jonbennett.co/lab/upload/

Comment: using this code in my custom functions file `function new_filename($filename, $filename_raw) {
    global $post;
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $new = $post->post_title . $ext;
    // the if is to make sure the script goes into an indefinate loop
    if( $new != $filename_raw ) {
        $new = sanitize_file_name( $new );
    }
    return $new;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'new_filename', 10, 2);`

Comment: Jon, please, add all relevant info in the Q itself.