# How to rename image on upload in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

I know this type of questions asked before but, i want image rename in my layout

how can i rename the image on uploading with wordpress upload.

Here is my image rename layout

```
lsp_image name_datetime.ext
```

Anyone please help me

Comment: Hi deemi... refere [WSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/rename-files-during-upload-using-variables)

Comment: another one.. [for media library](http://djzone.im/2011/01/change-uploaded-filename-in-wordpress-media-library/)

Comment: Sorry bro I dont want it with post id

Comment: ok.. download this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/file-renaming-on-upload/) and modify it as you need....!!

Comment: thanx to help me ... i find the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok i find the solution to rename the image on upload

here is my solution:

```
function lsp_rename_image($filename) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename($filename, $ext);
    return "lsp_".$name."_".date('dmy-his').$ext;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'lsp_rename_image', 10);
```

Comment: [FROM HERE!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259696/rename-files-during-upload-within-wordpress-backend)

Comment: changed return value to as you want instead of md5!!

Comment: yap i change the return value